# Executing stored procedure with date attached

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Everyday I have to run code that executes a stored procedure. I hard code yesterday's date after it.

EXECUTE sprm_example '2021-03-10'

I tried to do:

EXECUTE sprm_example 'getdate()-1'
EXECUTE sprm_example 'cast(getdate()-1 as date)'

Neither of these work, and it also doesn't work without quotes around it. Any ideas?

Comment: You run a piece of code manually every day. Why don't you use a trigger for that?

Comment: This is what SQL Agent excels at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow expressions in procedure calls but you can use a variable.  So:

```
declare @date date;

select @date = dateadd(day, -1, getdate());

EXECUTE sprm_example @date;
```